# Prevenir multiples instáncias de una App en Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo una actividad `AbouthisAcitivity` donde hay un enlace que envía al usuario  a la ficha de la aplicación en Googlelay.

En la ficha de Googleplay si se pulsa `Abrir App`, lo que hace es lanzar una nueva instancia de la Aplicación, mostrándose encima de todo.

Si se tira hacia atrás, se cierra la Aplicación y se muestra la actividad `AboutthisAcitivity` de la primera instancia de la App.

Para prevenir múltiples instancias de una Aplicación en Android, he encontrado:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Se debe establecer a la propiedad `android:launchMode` el valor `singleTask`

Pero en la [documentación oficial](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) hay más valores, como:

- multiple
- singleTop
- singleTask
- singleInstance

¿Que diferencia hay entre ellos, cual es más efectivo?

¿No sería más apropiado establecer el valor `singleInstance`, para sólo poder lanzar una instancia de la app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para prevenir multiples instancias lo apropiado para lanzar una instancia de la actividad, es lo que comentas, usar :

```
singleInstance
```

las dos opciones para abrir una instancia de aplicación son `singleTask` y `singleInstance`, al usar estas dos opciones se crean actividades en la raiz del stack y contendran siempre una instancia de la actividad.

La diferencia entre `singleTask` y `singleInstance` esta explicada en la [documentación](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

> `singleInstance` es similar a `singleTask`, excepto que el sistema no inicia
>   ninguna otra actividad en la tarea de la instancia. La actividad es
>   siempre el único miembro de su tarea.

Configura con `singleInstance` tu `MainActivity` dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`