# Evitar que intent recree una actividad

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación que necesita recibir texto de otras aplicaciones por ejemplo los links de youtube o spotify, esto se realiza con la opción de compartir de cada aplicación, y seleccionando mi aplicación en el cajón de aplicaciones para compartir.

Para recibir la url uso:

```
val txIntent = intent?.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
if (txIntent != null) {
    Log.i(TAG,txIntent)
}
```

La app recibe el texto con éxito, El problema esta en la forma como lo recibe.

**Nota**: lo explicado es con la aplicación ya abierta.
Mientras que al compartir desde YouTube el texto es recibido por medio de onNewIntent, ósea el comportamiento es el deseado.

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    Log.i(TAG,"NewIntent")

    val txIntent = intent?.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
    if (txIntent != null) {
        Log.i(TAG,txIntent)
    }
}
```

Si comparto el link desde Spotify o otra aplicación, la actividad se recrea, se llama a onCreate nuevamente, entonces tendría que colocar mi código en onCreate para poder recibirlo.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Log.i(TAG,"onCreate")

    val txIntent = intent?.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
    if (txIntent != null) {
        Log.i(TAG,txIntent)
    } 
}
```

Podría colocarlo sin ningún inconveniente, sin embargo el problema real es que la actividad se recrea, y no deseo eso, como dije antes al compartir desde youtube no se obtiene este comportamiento, se obtiene lo deseado desde onNewIntent y sin que la actividad se recree.
Supongo que se debe a la forma en como esta construido el intent, aun que es solo una suposición.

Entonces estuve investigando y encontré una posible solución y era agregar  `android:launchMode="singleTask"` en mi MainActivity en el Manifest. Esto funciona bien, recibo todo por medio de onNewIntent y la actividad no se recrea.

Sin embargo surge otro problema, es que si estoy en una segunda actividad y presiono el botón de home "No estoy cerrando la aplicación, solo presiono home, la aplicación sigue en segundo plano", y luego ingreso presionando el icono de la aplicación, esta se abre en MainActivity en lugar de SecondActivity que es donde la deje. Comportamiento que no sucede si no se usa  `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, ya que hay si se abre la ultima actividad en la que se estuvo.

Según lo que entiendo este es un comportamiento natural de singleTask.
Entonces como puedo recibir intents, sin que mi actividad se recree y regresando a la ultima actividad en la que estuve, al regresar a la aplicación.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:exported="true" />
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
         //android:launchMode="singleTask"  -----
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre debe haber una vez en la cual se creen la Activity, si deseas que no se recree la Activity por ejemplo cuando esta se rota define en el `AndroidManifest.xml` el atributo y valor:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Ejemplo:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            />
```

En cuanto a el atributo `android:launchMode="singleTask"` este define que siempre se encontrará una instancia de tu Activity, es decir se mantendrá la activity en la raiz del stack y contendrá siempre una instancia de la actividad.

Revisa:

**[Prevenir multiples instáncias de una App en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9369/prevenir-multiples-inst%C3%A1ncias-de-una-app-en-android)**

de acuerdo a :

> Según lo que entiendo este es un comportamiento natural de singleTask.
> Entonces como puedo recibir intents, sin que mi actividad se recree y
> regresando a la ultima actividad en la que estuve, al regresar a la
> aplicación.

Si, pero recuerda que si el sistema operativo requiere la memoria de tu aplicación(por ejemplo cuando navegas otras aplicaciones y regresas nuevamente a tu app), la activity podría destruirse por lo que se crearía nuevamente.